# Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field '_code@28251533' has not been initialized

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a class called sale

```
class Sale{
  late String code;
  late String shop;
  late String user;
  late double qty;
  late DateTime dateTime;

}
```

after setting state as below

```
onPressed:  ()async {
        setState(() {
          _sale.code="1234luja";
          _sale.qty=300;
          _sale.user="luja";
          _sale.shop="namcholi";
        });
}
```

I am getting **Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError:** below is my **database.dart**

```
  Future addSale(Sale sale)async{
    return await db.doc("Sales").collection(sale.shop).add({"code":sale.code,"qty":sale.qty,"user":sale.user,"date":DateTime.now()
    });

  }
```

Below is where I am calling the **addSale**:

```
        if(_formKey.currentState!.validate()){
          setState(() {
            loading = true;
          });
          dynamic res = await dbService.addSale(_sale);
          if(res==null){
            setState(() {
              error = "Please enter valid user and email";
              loading = false;
            });
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                const SnackBar(
                  duration: const Duration(seconds: 6),
                  content: Text('Please enter valid user and email',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                )
            );
          }

        }else{
          print('form invalid');
        }
```

Comment: Could you add the full error message? It should contain information pointing at where you are trying to use the problematic value before it is set.

Comment: ```E/flutter (32735): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field 'shop' has not been initialized.
E/flutter (32735): #0      Sale.shop (package:myshop/models/Sale.dart)
E/flutter (32735): #1      Database.addSale 
(package:myshop/Services/Database.dart:68:50)```

Comment: So, it looks like you are sending a `sale` object into `addSale` which has yet to be initialized. It is impossible for me to tell you exactly what you should do since the problem is properly in some code you have not showed us. Try with a debugger do find out what your flow of your program is and find out how you end up calling `addSale` before `setState`.